# jQuery Load with jQuery Tabs - Unobtrusive Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, unobtrusive

I am using **jQuery Tabs** and I am loading the tab pages using the **tabsbeforeactivate** event, so that I only load contents when needed through **Ajax**.

I am facing difficulties since I need to manually enable Unobrusive Validation after injecting the respective contents. I am using the **$('#tabs-0').load** and the **$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(result));** when completed.

I don't know why but I still don't get the Unobtrusive Validation.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using the **Load** Callback Function.

When the **Load** mehtod is completed I call the:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(result))
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/